# WPF c# Filter doesn't work correctly after Sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, filtering

I have a WPF Gridview and three buttons.  Two Sort and one applys a filter.  They all work independently.  The problem is that after sorting, i have to click the filter button and then the sort button again to get the filter to apply.  I'm hoping this is something simple with the Items.SortDescriptions and Items.Refresh().  If not, i'm sure you'll let me know, and I'll add more.

```
    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        DataList.Clear();
        foreach(FilterItem f in FilterList){
            if (f.isChecked && listBox.Items.IndexOf(f) > -1 ) {
                DataList.Add(f.Name);
            }
        }
        myListView.Items.Refresh();
        this.contextFilter.IsOpen = false;
    }

    private void btnSortAsc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        SortDescription sa = new SortDescription("", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        myListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        myListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(sa);
        this.contextFilter.IsOpen = false;
    }

    private void btnSortDec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
        myListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        myListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
        this.contextFilter.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Looks like the sort is clearing the filter. OP - what is the type of your DataList? You may also want look into using the DataGrid (which has build it sorting by clicking on the column header) along with ICollectionView (which has filtering, sorting ...).

Comment: Also, having Sort buttons doesn't seem very user friendly. Most users are going to expect to be able to click on a column header to sort.

Comment: Djerry: I expect the filter to be applied when the btnApply_Click code runs.  It doesn't.  My first question is why?  That answer may be enough for me to fix it.  If not, the second question will be: How do i rework so that the filter is applied when btnApply_Click is run?

Comment: KornMuffin: Here's the 

    DataList:private List<string> DataList = new List<string>();

And I am using this as the gridview:
    
        <ListView Name="myListView">
          <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Name="colHeader" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_MouseUp">First Column</GridViewColumnHeader>       
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

Comment: KornMuffin: I understand your concern and initially thought of doing it that way.  However, that decision is not mine to make.

Comment: Passed my 5 minute mark on that comment with the code trying to figure out this mini-Markdown formatting. Sorry.

Comment: @jnewt: try myListView.Items.Clear() and myListView.Items.Add() instead of DataList.Clear() / Add() in your Apply Filter method. Also check out the following [link](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/) which really is more of the route that you should be going if you plan on doing more complex data dislays.

Comment: MyListView.Items.Clear() throws an InvalidOperationException  and states that Operation is not valid while ItemsSoruce is in use.  Access and modify elements with the ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.  Now the source is the DataList, so I don't think i can do what you recommend.  Do I really need to switch my methodolgy to the icollectionview stuff just to solve this problem, or is is simply a "better" way of doing things?